# How to call value from properties in AutoIT script?

Tags: selenium, autoit

I have the script in AutoIT (to handle upload file window in selenium)

```
    WinWaitActive("File Upload")
    Send("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Folder1\MyFile.xlsx")
    Send("{ENTER}")
```

Instead of hard-coding pathname, I want to pick-up pathname from a property file.(So that tomorrow we dont to touch AutoIT script to modify pathname).

Is there any way to do so?

Update 1:
`java` code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TestUtility.properties.getProperty("test.all.autoit.testdata"));
Thread.sleep(8000);
```

`AutoIT` code:

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send($CmdLine[1])
Send("{ENTER}")
```

`Cmd` line:

```
c:>java -jar pathToJar.jar pathToProperties.properties pathToFileUpload.xlsx
```

`Properties` file:

```
test.all.autoit.testdata='C:\\XX\\XX\\XX\\someFolder\\ListUploadScript.exe'
```

Comment: why you want to handle file uploading using `AutoIT` instead of `Selenium`?!

Comment: @Andersson Since selenium can not handle window pop-up, need to use AutoIT to handle file upload popup.

Comment: `selenium` allow to upload file without handling pop-up

Comment: @Andersson If it is web-based popup. Selenium is not feasible when it comes to window (OS) based pop-up.

Comment: no, I mean avoid handling `OS` native pop-up

Comment: You just need to send path to file straight to input element

Comment: provide `html` for a button intended to open file upload pop-up and programming language you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is AutoIt script can accept command line parameter for invoking so my Java test use to read that property from properties file and then when I invoke AutoIt script I invoke it with the property as command line option to the AutoIt script and accept that command line argument in AutoIt script as the path to the file to be uploaded. Let me know if this works for you!!! 
Also if your upload button is of type input then no need use AutoIt..directly `element.sendKeys(<Path to upload file>)` should work
Sample Code:

```
WinActivate("File Upload")
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send($CmdLine[1])
Send("{Enter}")
```

Here `$CmdLine[1]` accepts the first command line argument passed. so while calling this script (.exe) call it in this way.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("src/test/resources/fileupload.exe "+path);
```

where path is the path to the file which you wish to upload.
I assume you would already know when to call your AutoIt script :D 
EDIT1 : $CmdLine[0] is reserved to get count of number of command line arguments passed to autoit script..so the actual arguments start with $CmdLine[1] which is the first argument passed on command line. 
EDIT2: I am assuming you are running from a main method, if so then your call to execute autoIt script should be like this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TestUtility.properties.getProperty("test.all.autoit.testdata")+" "+args[0]);`
where args[0] is the args array passed as argument to main method whose 0th Index has excel sheet which you wish to pass. Also you need to pass absolute path of the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more.

Comment: Mrunal,Thanks for code.
AutoIT script:
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send($CmdLine[0])
Send("{ENTER}")
my way to call .exe from selenium script is Runtime.getruntime().exec("path-to-property-file");
From cmd-line,I trigger script by:
d:>java -jar myjar.jar mypropertyfile.properties path-to-file-to-be-uploaded.
Script is executed.But it displays error message ---Line2(File"pathname-to-exe");
error:Array variable has incorrect number of subscripts or subscript dimension range exceeded.

Please guide me in resolving the error.

Comment: $CmdLine[0] is reserved to get count of number of command line arguments passed to autoit script..so the actual arguments start with $CmdLine[1] which is the first argument passed on command line.

Comment: Also, line---

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("src/test/resources/fileupload.exe "+path);

is not feasible as I dont want to hard-code path-to-file-to-be-uploaded anywhere in the selenium and autoit script.

User should enter the path-to-file-to-be-uploaded as argument in cmd line.

Comment: Simple Then use that argument like Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args[0]+" "+args[1]) where args[0] is the autoit script path passed in command line and args[1] is the file upload path specified in command line.

Comment: I tried with $CmdLine[1] (even 2,3,4) in the autoit script, still facing same error as

Line2(File"pathname-to-exe"); error:Array variable has incorrect number of subscripts or subscript dimension range exceeded.

Comment: Can you post complete code with java class and autoit script code to the original question..Let me take a look

Comment: Error I am getting is :

Line 2(File"C:\\XX\\XX\\XX\\someFolder\\ListUploadScript.exe");

Error:Array variable has incorrect  number of subscripts or subscript dimension range exceeded

Comment: No,I am not running from main method. I am running runtime.getruntime()...from class Testutility.java.

When I add Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TestUtility.properties.getProperty("test.all.autoit.testdata")+" "+args[0]);

It shows error in args[0] cannot be resolved to variable.

Comment: So from whereever you are calling that statement probably from another method you need to pass some parameter / argument to that method specifying the absolute excel sheet and that argument u can use instead of args[0]..Buddy this is some basic java

Comment: I will check it out.

Comment: As far as the original question is concerned i believe that is answered..would u consider accepting this as answer so as to help others looking for such queries to find answer easily

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ini files with `IniRead` and `IniWrite` functions

The file look like :

> [SectionName]
>
> KeyName1=Value
>
> KeyName2=Value

And you read in the file with :

```
IniRead('nom_fichier.ini', 'SectionName', 'KeyName1', 'Default Value')
```